# PHP XPath to change stylesheet

Tags: php, xpath

I use xpath to change stylesheet of `href` of stylesheet `<link>` in header.

But it doesn't work at all.

```
$html=file_get_contents('http://stackoverflow.com');
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($html);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
$css_links = $xpath->evaluate("//link[@type='text/css']");
for ($i = 0; $i < $css_links->length; $i++) 
{
    $csslink = $css_links->item($i);
    $oldurl = $csslink->getAttribute('href');
    $newURL='http://example.com/aaaa.css';
    $csslink->removeAttribute('href');
    $csslink->setAttribute('href', $newURL);
}
echo $html;
```

Comment: Is [fopen wrappers](http://www.php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-fopen) enabled to get content from external source? And why do you suppress error message with @-notation? Maybe there is your answer.

Comment: @mamuz,yes, according to phpinfo it is on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using `@$doc->loadHTML(html);` instead of `@$doc->loadHTML($html);` (note the `$`), otherwise it works.

Also use `echo $doc->SaveHtml()` instead of echoing `$html`.

Working example [here](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/wx0-k62).

You also can replace `for($i...)` with `foreach` because [`DOMNodeList implements Traversable`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domnodelist.php):

```
foreach ($css_links as $csslink) 
{
    $oldurl = $csslink->getAttribute('href');
```